# Call one function after another to get the proper url

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

Hi I am working in grails ..

```
<g:link name="searchLink" controller="MRController"  
action="ExcelExport">TEST GRAILS</g:link>

<script>
        $(function() {
            $('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
            $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?startdate=' + start().StartDate +'&enddate=' + start().Enddate);
            })
            })


       function start(){

        var StartDate =  $("#startDate").val();
        var Enddate=  $("#endDate").val();
        return {StartDate:StartDate,Enddate:Enddate}
        }
    </script>
```

I have trying to get the following url

```
 http://localhost:8077/Myproject/MRController/ExcelExport  
 ?startdate=2017-05-21&enddate=2017-05-23
```

But when i click the link again i get the following url instead i want the link with new startdate and enddate value

```
 http://localhost:8077/Myproject/MRController/ExcelExport?  
 startdate=2017-05-21&enddate=2017-05-23?startdate=2017-05-21&enddate=2017-05-23
```

**Edited**

I have tried with the following script to clear the parameters in the first call but i don't know how to make the script run one after another means first the url call work then the parameters will clear through the function

```
<script>
function refineUrl()
        {   
        //get full url
        var url = window.location.href;
        //get url after/  
        var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        //get the part after before ?
        value  = value.split("?")[0];
        return value; 
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the original `href` attribute in your JS-code:

```
$('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
    document.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?startdate=' + start().StartDate +'&enddate=' + start().Enddate;            
})
```

Comment: It is not working giving the wrong url http://localhost:8077/Myproject/MRController/ExcelExport